# Entity Framework Code First Migrations Seeing Old Column Type When Creating View

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a project using Entity Framework's Code-First migrations.

In migration A, I change the type of a column from `float` to `decimal`, which looks like the following in the migration:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.InvoiceLineItemEvents", "Amount", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
        AlterColumn("dbo.InvoiceLineItemEvents", "PurchaseOrderUnitCost", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.InvoiceLineItemEvents", "PurchaseOrderUnitCost", c => c.Double(nullable: false));
        AlterColumn("dbo.InvoiceLineItemEvents", "Amount", c => c.Double(nullable: false));
    }
```

In subsequent migration B, I want to change a view that was built using those columns (among others). The view was not created with schemabinding and was created in a previous EF migration. Migration B looks like (edited for length):

```
public override void Up()
{
  Sql("DROP VIEW [dbo].[CurrentSpend]");
  Sql(@"CREATE VIEW [dbo].[CurrentSpend] AS
    <omit lengthy creation of new version of view>
  ");
}

public override void Down()
{
  Sql("DROP VIEW [dbo].[CurrentSpend]");
  Sql(@"
    <omit lengthy creation of old version of view>
  ");
}
```

When I run Update-Database on an empty database, migration B fails on creating the view. Within the new version of the view I use the modulo operator (%), and EF spits out the following message:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The data types decimal and float are incompatible in the modulo operator.
```

Viewing the database I see that the migration record table has been updated to point to migration A (and all the preceding migrations, natch). If I run Update-Database *again*, though, EF seems to suddenly pick up on the fact that the column datatypes have changed, and proceeds to apply migration B without incident!

What on earth is going on here? I was under the impression that EF migrations happened inside a transaction and that it was a safe bet that migration B would *always* observe any schema OR data changes from a preceding migration.